# liferay-ui:captcha customization/localization in Liferay 6.2

Tags: liferay, liferay-6, liferay-aui

After migration to Liferay 6.2 `<liferay-ui:captcha>` customization stopped working:

- original input is no longer hidden
- refresh link appeared (we need it hidden, or translate label and remove bugged tooltip - it flickers on hover)

LFR 6.1 code:

```
xmlns:form="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" 
xmlns:liferay-ui="http://liferay.com/tld/ui"

<liferay-ui:captcha url="${captchaURL}"/>
<label for="captchaText" >
    Opiste text z obrazku
</label>
<form:input id="captchaText" path="captcha"  />
```

What is the proper way to customize captcha component?

I tried replacing our ids to match ids of fields generated by Liferay, but it did not work.

Code generated by Liferay:

```
<div class="taglib-captcha" id="yui_patched_v3_11_0_1_1425121596007_13262">
    <img alt="Text to Identify" class="captcha"
         id="_pspmlmuserportlet_WAR_pspmlmuserportlet_captcha"
         src="..."/>
    <span class="refresh" onmouseover="Liferay.Portal.ToolTip.show(this, 'Refresh CAPTCHA')" 
          data-title="" id="yui_patched_v3_11_0_1_1425121596007_13261"> 

        <a href="javascript:;" class=" taglib-icon" id="_pspmlmuserportlet_WAR_pspmlmuserportlet_refreshCaptcha">
            <img id="refreshCaptcha" src=".../refresh.png" alt="Refresh CAPTCHA" title="Refresh CAPTCHA"/> 
            <span class="taglib-text hide-accessible">Refresh CAPTCHA</span> 
        </a> 
    </span>

    <div class="form-group" id="yui_patched_v3_11_0_1_1425121596007_14890">
        <label class="control-label" for="_pspmlmuserportlet_WAR_pspmlmuserportlet_captchaText"> 
            Text Verification <span class="label-required">(Required)</span>
        </label>
        <input class="field  form-control" id="_pspmlmuserportlet_WAR_pspmlmuserportlet_captchaText"
               name="_pspmlmuserportlet_WAR_pspmlmuserportlet_captchaText" type="text" value="" size="10"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

I can probably do it by jQuery, but I would be interested in a proper way to do it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way should be working in ext environment, for modify your UI taglib code... I'm not sure you can hook a taglib.

Comment: So Liferay 6.2 does not support any customization even though Liferay 6.1 was?

Comment: LR is pushing toward increasing the capabilities of customization... so generally speaking, you can customize in 6.2 at least the same things that  in 6.1 (sorry if my answer can be differently interpreted). By the way it is possible that (for the same user behaviour) in 6.2 the code is different than in 6.1... so you should customize your behaviour starting by 6.2 source code and trying to apply what you need over.

Answer (score 0):

You can customize the UI taglib: captcha via hook. Here's an example [enter link description here](https://gist.github.com/amusarra/55b971f083251cbc0f2f). In this example I set the theme of the reCaptcha via properties.

Answer (score 0):

Liferay 6.2 code for create a simple captcha

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://alloy.liferay.com/tld/aui" prefix="aui"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://liferay.com/tld/ui" prefix="liferay-ui" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://liferay.com/tld/theme" prefix="liferay-theme" %>
```

This URL will be invoked before showing the CAPTCHA image

```
<portlet:resourceURL var="captchaURL"/>
```

This is the Html code to display the image

```
<aui:column columnWidth="10" first="true">
<div class="input-piwest-captcha">
<liferay-ui:captcha url="<%=captchaURL%>" />
</div>
<div class="input-piwest-captchaError">
<liferay-ui:error key="errorMessage" message="Code does not match. Please try again."/>
</div>
</aui:column>
```

Java Code

```
import com.liferay.portal.kernel.captcha.CaptchaException;
import com.liferay.portal.kernel.captcha.CaptchaUtil;

  @ResourceMapping
public void serveResource(ResourceRequest resourceRequest,
        ResourceResponse resourceResponse) throws IOException  {
        CaptchaUtil.serveImage(resourceRequest, resourceResponse);
}



 private String getCaptchaValueFromSession(PortletSession session) {
        Enumeration<String> atNames = session.getAttributeNames();
        while (atNames.hasMoreElements()) {
            String name = atNames.nextElement();
            if (name.contains("CAPTCHA_TEXT")) {
                return (String) session.getAttribute(name);
            }
        }
        return null;
    }



    Validate the CAPTCHA TEXT

          PortletSession session = actionRequest.getPortletSession();
          String enteredCaptchaText = ParamUtil.getString(actionRequest, "captchaText");
            String captchaText = getCaptchaValueFromSession(session);

            if (Validator.isNull(captchaText) || !StringUtils.equals(captchaText, enteredCaptchaText)) {
                throw new CaptchaException("Invalid captcha text. Please reenter.");
            }
```